# Redirecting a button-click to an invisible element (Google SignIn)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here is a picture of my authentication UI:

[image: First screen]

I wish I could redesign the `GoogleSignInButton` to look like what I have pictured there, but it seems like it's a hard task to customize that button. As it is now, clicking on "GOOGLE" brings you to this other view:

[image: Screen to avoid]

As you might have understood, that isn't a good design in terms of user-friendliness: it requires an extra-click for no reason. **I have thought of two options to get rid of that extra-click**:

1. Hide the `GoogleSignInButton` on the first view and when a user clicks on the "GOOGLE" button, it would trigger a click on that hidden button.
2. Somehow find out how to customize the `GoogleSignInButton` properly to obtain what I want.

**In both cases, I do not know how to achieve my goal.**

Could anyone help me?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add your custom button, and google button to your xml layout

2) Hide Google button with `View.GONE`

3) In your activity/fragment find both views by id's

```
val customButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.custom_button)
val googleButton = findViewById<GoogleSignInButton>(R.id.google_button)
```

4) Setup an onClickListener on your custom button, that will perform the click on the Google button.

```
customButton.setOnClickListener { googleButton.performClick() }
```

Comment: Looks like what I was looking for. I'm currently in my exam session, so I don't have much time to try to implement it. Once I get to try it out, if it works, I'll mark your reply as the answer. **`performClick()` is what I was looking for.** Thank you very much, buddy! :)